# How to create two lists which contain 10 instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, operators

ive just started learning python and stuck here:

create two lists called `x_list` and `y_list`, which contain 10 instances of the variables `x` and `y`, respectively.

You are also required to create a list called `big_list`, which contains the variables `x` and `y`, 10 times each, by concatenating the two lists you have created.

Comment: Please add some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you read more about the python docs, and `list` docs, you can find it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

but you can do it as this:

```py
x_list = [x]*10 # Create list with 10 vars of the value of x
y_list = [y]*10
big_list = x_list + y_list # conact two list into one
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the list by python operators.

```
x_list = [1] * 10 #This is for example.  
y_list = [2] * 10 #This is for example.  

x_y_list = (x_list + y_list)
print(x_y_list)
```

x_y_list gives the resulting list